# connect to snowflake via odbc driver on mac m1

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-desktop

According to [this](https://kb.tableau.com/articles/Issue/unable-to-connect-to-snowflake-with-tableau-desktop-on-macos-with-m1-processor), if I read this correctly, Tableau desktop on a Mac M1 cannot use the snowflake ODBC driver. Is this still true? Generally, my ODBC driver for snowflake works.

[image]

PS:

@aek I still get:

[image]

in Tableau. I installed:

2.25.3  snowflake_odbc_mac-2.25.3.dmg   mac64

and configured odbc.ini files and everything appears to work fine in:

[image]

If I run (as suggested [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html#step-1-install-the-odbc-driver)):

```
"/Library/Application Support/iODBC/bin/iodbctest"
```

I get:

```
1: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]dlopen(/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/opt/snowflake/snowflakeodbc/lib/universal/libSnowflake.dylib' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64')) (0) SQLSTATE=00000
2: SQLDriverConnect = [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded (0) SQLSTATE=IM003
```

Is there anything I can/have to do that Tableau recognised the driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is still true (for v. 2022.3). According to the [spec](https://www.tableau.com/products/techspecs), Tableau Desktop still works in emulation mode. The application and driver must have the same architecture. So for Tableau Desktop, you need to use the Mac64 version of the driver, as the article suggests.

Edit: How to make it working.
The native Snowflake connector in Tableau will try to use the "OS architecture appropriate" driver. Which is not the case for an x64 app running on ARM. Therefore, when configuring the connection, instead of choosing Snowflake from the list, you should use Other Databases (ODBC) and select the Snowflake DSN configured with the Mac64 version of the driver accordingly to the [doc](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc-mac.html).

Comment: Thanks - please see further comments under PS above

Comment: @cs0815 In Tableau when setup a new connection, Instead of choosing Snowflake from the list, try Other Databases (ODBC) it should have an option to select the DSN you have configured for the Mac64 driver.

Comment: You are a star!!! Thanks. This drove me almost mad (-: Maybe adapt answer and I accept?